Android: What is the best way to access ViewModel method from Broadcast receiver?
I have a viewmodel with a method Refresh(), which accesses DB and updates UI. I need to call this method whenever Airplane mode changes.
How to do this?
Implementation of Broadcast receiver:
class AirplaneModeChanged() : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        if (p1?.action?.equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) == true) {
            /* MyViewModel.refresh() */
        }
    }
}


Implementation of Viewmodel:
class MyViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun refresh() 
    { 
        /* Access DB and update UI */ 
    }

}



MainActivity:
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity(), LifecycleOwner {
    private val viewModel: MyViewModel by viewModels()
    private val airplaneModeChanged = AirplaneModeChanged()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        ContextCompat.registerReceiver(applicationContext, airplaneModeChanged, IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED),
            ContextCompat.RECEIVER_NOT_EXPORTED)

    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceiver(airplaneModeChanged)
    }
}



The best way is to not try to access your ViewModel from the BroadcastReceiver. Instead, have both of these classes call a third class that does what you want done.
class MyDataSource { 
    fun fetchData(){}
}

Then you can do
class AirplaneModeChanged(val dataSource : MyDataSource) : BroadcastReceiver() {

    override fun onReceive(p0: Context?, p1: Intent?) {
        if (p1?.action?.equals(Intent.ACTION_AIRPLANE_MODE_CHANGED) == true) {
            dataSource.fetchData()
        }
    }
}

and
class MyViewModel(application: Application, val dataSource : MyDataSource) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    fun refresh() 
    { 
        dataSource.fetchData()
    }

}


Thanks for the response.
What if I have only business logic to do with no DB access? In those cases, how can I access the business logic from BroadcastReceiver?

@Saral It really depends on what it does. You could inject the thing that does the business logic to your broadcast receiver for isntance

What I intended to ask was is there any way to invoke methods defined in ViewModel.

Thanks Ivan, I will create a third class for my case, that's the right way to go.
